# Which is faster and why? Set or List?

Tags: python, list, graph, set

Lets say that I have a graph and want to see if `b in N[a]`. Which is the faster implementation and why?

```
a, b = range(2)
N = [set([b]), set([a,b])]
```

OR

```
N= [[b],[a,b]]
```

This is obviously oversimplified, but imagine that the graph becomes really dense.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Membership testing in a set is vastly faster, especially for large sets. That is because the set uses a [hash function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function) to map to a bucket. Since Python implementations automatically resize that hash table, the speed can be constant ([`O(1)`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/O_notation)) no matter the size of the set (assuming the hash function is sufficiently good).

In contrast, to evaluate whether an object is a member of a list, Python has to compare every single member for equality, i.e. the test is `O(n)`.

Comment: Beat me to it.  It's also worth pointing out that the OP has a list of lists in the first example, and a list of sets in the second.  Because the outer container is a list in both situations, the search is O(n) in both situations.

Comment: Python sets are dynamically resized hashtables, so you get amortized O(1) regardless of the number of items. @g.d.d.c OP asks about membership tests for *a single item* (`b in N[a]`) of the list of containers that is `N`, so no it isn't O(n) either way.

Comment: @delnan You're right, `O(1)` (+notes) is a better description than `O(log n)` (-notes).

Comment: @phihag O(1) isn't just better than O(log n):  O(1) is correct, and O(log n) is not.

Comment: @NedBatchelder: Actually, if you look up the mathematical definition, you'll find that O(log N) is correct whenever O(1) is – if it's constant, it's also bounded by log N. So O(1) *is* “just” better than O(log N).

Comment: @PetrViktorin: yes, that is part of the definition of big-O, so you are correct.  O(log n) is not wrong, it is simply misleading and useless! :)  Other correct descriptions of the membership testing of a set are O(N**2), O(N**N), O(N**N**N), etc, etc.

Comment: @NedBatchelder You're right. My instinct was to quote O(log n) because that's what's achievable no matter the precise tuning (of bucket numbers and hash functions), but `O(1)` is the correct description here. Fixed.

Answer (score 5):

It all depends on what you're trying to accomplish. Using your example verbatim, it's faster to use lists, as you don't have to go through the overhead of creating the sets:

```
import timeit

def use_sets(a, b):
    return [set([b]), set([a, b])]

def use_lists(a, b):
    return [[b], [a, b]]

t=timeit.Timer("use_sets(a, b)", """from __main__ import use_sets
a, b = range(2)""")
print "use_sets()", t.timeit(number=1000000)

t=timeit.Timer("use_lists(a, b)", """from __main__ import use_lists
a, b = range(2)""")
print "use_lists()", t.timeit(number=1000000)
```

Produces:

```
use_sets() 1.57522511482
use_lists() 0.783344984055
```

However, for reasons already mentioned here, you benefit from using sets when you are *searching* large sets. It's impossible to tell by your example where that inflection point is  for you and whether or not you'll see the benefit.

I suggest you test it both ways and go with whatever is faster for your specific use-case.

Comment: It's because in order to create a set you first create a list. So it cannot be faster than only creating a list, by definition. **If you initialize sets via `{}` the results are comparable to list initialization.**

Answer (score 3):

Set ( I mean a hash based set like HashSet) is much faster than List to lookup for a value. List has to go sequentially to find out if the value exists. HashSet can directly jump and locate the bucket and look up for a value almost in a constant time.