# python prime numbers Sieve of Eratosthenes

Tags: python, performance, primes

Hi can anyone tell me how to implement Sieve of Eratosthenes within this code to make it fast? Help will be really appreciated if you can complete it with sieve. I am really having trouble doing this in this particular code.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys

T=10 #no of test cases
t=open(sys.argv[1],'r').readlines()

import math
def is_prime(n):
    if n == 2:
        return True
    if n%2 == 0 or n <= 1:
        return False
    sqr = int(math.sqrt(n)) + 1
    for divisor in range(3, sqr, 2):
        if n%divisor == 0:
            return False
    return True

#first line of each test case
a=[1,4,7,10,13,16,19,22,25,28]
count=0
for i in a:

    b=t[i].split(" ")
    c=b[1].split("\n")[0]
    b=b[0]

    for k in xrange(int(b)):
        d=t[i+1].split(" ")

        e=t[i+2].split(" ")
        for g in d:
            for j in e:
                try:
                    sum=int(g)+int(j)
                    p=is_prime(sum)         
                    if p==True:
                        count+=1
                        print count
                    else:
                        pass
                except:
                    try:
                        g=g.strip("\n")
                        sum=int(g)+int(j)
                        p=is_prime(sum)
                        if p==True:
                            count+=1
                            print count
                        else:
                            pass
                    except:
                        j=j.strip("\n")
                        sum=int(g)+int(j)
                        p=is_prime(sum)
                        if p==True:
                            count+=1
                            print count
                        else:
                            pass

print "Final count"+count
```

Comment: related: [Fastest way to list all primes below N in python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2068372/4279)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

An old trick for speeding sieves in Python is to use fancy ;-) list slice notation, like below.  This uses Python 3.  Changes needed for Python 2 are noted in comments:

```
def sieve(n):
    "Return all primes <= n."
    np1 = n + 1
    s = list(range(np1)) # leave off `list()` in Python 2
    s[1] = 0
    sqrtn = int(round(n**0.5))
    for i in range(2, sqrtn + 1): # use `xrange()` in Python 2
        if s[i]:
            # next line:  use `xrange()` in Python 2
            s[i*i: np1: i] = [0] * len(range(i*i, np1, i))
    return filter(None, s)
```

In Python 2 this returns a list; in Python 3 an iterator.  Here under Python 3:

```
>>> list(sieve(20))
[2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19]
>>> len(list(sieve(1000000)))
78498
```

Those both run in an eyeblink.  Given that, here's how to build an `is_prime` function:

```
primes = set(sieve(the_max_integer_you_care_about))
def is_prime(n):
    return n in primes
```

It's the `set()` part that makes it fast.  Of course the function is so simple you'd probably want to write:

```
if n in primes:
```

directly instead of messing with:

```
if is_prime(n):
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but now when primes are generated. they are not compared with the sum of numbers in list so the whole code is faster.

Comment: code is faster then before thanks a lot. But the sum part and compare part is still slow :(

Comment: @user2876096, if you need more help, I think you should open a new question, showing the exact code you're using **now**.  *This* question was about using a sieve, and has already been answered ;-)

Comment: thanks  I got it working. Now it solves 50000x50000 lists in 7 minutes :) Thanks a lot all for help.

Comment: @Tim Peters Thank you for the excellent answer! For the purpose of this sieve sqrtn = int(n**0.5)  should be enough, right?

Comment: @Ajay Yadav, better safe than sorry.  For example, consider `n=169`.  Exponentiation is implemented by taking a logarithm under the covers, multiplying by the power, and then raising the base of the logarithm to that result.  Depending on platform math library quirks, 169**0.5 _may_ come out to, say, 13.000000000001 or to 12.99999999999 instead of exactly 13.0.  Using `round()` instead of `int()` guards against that (`int(12.99999999)` would return 12, not the 13 needed here).

Answer (score 10):

Both the original poster and the other solution posted here make the same mistake; if you use the modulo operator, or division in any form, your algorithm is trial division, *not* the Sieve of Eratosthenes, and will be far slower, O(n^2) instead of O(n log log n). Here is a simple Sieve of Eratosthenes in Python:

```
def primes(n): # sieve of eratosthenes
    ps, sieve = [], [True] * (n + 1)
    for p in range(2, n + 1):
        if sieve[p]:
           ps.append(p)
           for i in range(p * p, n + 1, p):
               sieve[i] = False
    return ps
```

That should find all the primes less than a million in less than a second. If you're interested in programming with prime numbers, I modestly recommend this [essay](http://programmingpraxis.com/essays) at my blog.

Comment: when i add your code as it is the i get error nameerror is_prime not defined

Comment: Can you please update it in my posted code. I am not able to figure it how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Fastest implementation I could think of

```
def sieve(maxNum):
    yield 2
    D, q = {}, 3
    while q <= maxNum:
        p = D.pop(q, 0)
        if p:
            x = q + p
            while x in D: x += p
            D[x] = p
        else:
            yield q
            D[q*q] = 2*q
        q += 2
    raise StopIteration
```

Source: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/117119-sieve-of-eratosthenes/#c4

Replace this part

```
import math
def is_prime(n):
    if n == 2:
        return True
    if n%2 == 0 or n <= 1:
        return False
    sqr = int(math.sqrt(n)) + 1
    for divisor in range(3, sqr, 2):
        if n%divisor == 0:
            return False
    return True
```

with

```
primes = [prime for prime in sieve(10000000)]
def is_prime(n):
    return n in primes
```

Instead of `10000000` you can put whatever the maximum number till which you need prime numbers.

Comment: How i put it in this code?? can u tell how i apply this in above code? Will be very helpful

Comment: It became more slower :(

Comment: What did you give instead of 10000000?

Comment: @user2876096 No it is not. I have given you the code to used instead of `is_prime`. Use that.

Comment: the `sieve` algo that you show must be used in [postponed variation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10733621/849891). It uses much less memory and becomes a bit faster too.

Comment: Can you please update it in my posted code. I am not able to figure it how to do it...

Comment: when i add your code as it is the i get error nameerror is_prime not defined

Comment: @thefourtheye, I bet your code was slower because you left `primes` as a list, so `n in primes` does a slow linear search.  Wrap it in a `set()`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very fast generator with reduced memory usage.

```
def pgen(maxnum): # Sieve of Eratosthenes generator
    yield 2
    np_f = {}
    for q in xrange(3, maxnum + 1, 2):
        f = np_f.pop(q, None)
        if f:
            while f != np_f.setdefault(q+f, f):
                q += f
        else:
            yield q
            np = q*q
            if np < maxnum:  # does not add to dict beyond maxnum
                np_f[np] = q+q

def is_prime(n):
    return n in pgen(n)

>>> is_prime(541)
True
>>> is_prime(539)
False
>>> 83 in pgen(100)
True
>>> list(pgen(100)) # List prime numbers less than or equal to 100
[2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83,
89, 97]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple generator using only addition that does not pre-allocate memory. The sieve is only as large as the dictionary of primes and memory use grows only as needed.

```
def pgen(maxnum): # Sieve of Eratosthenes generator
    pnext, ps = 2, {}
    while pnext <= maxnum:
        for p in ps:
            while ps[p] < pnext:
                ps[p] += p
            if ps[p] == pnext:
                break
        else:
            ps[pnext] = pnext
            yield pnext
        pnext += 1

def is_prime(n):
    return n in pgen(n)

>>> is_prime(117)
>>> is_prime(117)
False
>>> 83 in pgen(83)
True
>>> list(pgen(100)) # List prime numbers less than or equal to 100
[2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83,
89, 97]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple solution with sets.
Which is very fast in comparison with many of the list-algorithms.
Computation with sets is much faster because of the hash tables.
([What makes sets faster than lists in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8929284/what-makes-sets-faster-than-lists-in-python))

Greetings

```
----------------------------------
from math import *

def sievePrimes(n):

    numbers = set()
    numbers2 = set()
    bound = round(sqrt(n))

    for a in range(2, n+1):
        numbers.add(a)

    for i in range(2, n):
        for b in range(1, bound):
            if (i*(b+1)) in numbers2:
                continue
            numbers2.add(i*(b+1))
    numbers = numbers - numbers2

    print(sorted(numbers))
```

---

[Simple Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQf6O.png)