# How to remove an item from a list if its in one or two (or N) other lists

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have a parent list called `parent_list`, and two subsets via which I'm to filter the `parent_list`. These subsets are also python lists, and they're called `filter1` and `filter2`.

Can I do:

```
final_list = [object for object in parent_list if object.pk not in filter1 or filter2]
```

Or will I need to do this filteration separately, as in:

```
intermediate_list = [object for object in parent_list if object.pk not in filter1]
final_list = [object for object in intermediate_list if object.pk not in filter2]
```

I couldn't explicitly find the answer from the documentation on python list comprehensions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use sets for fast look up of the items:

```
final_list = [object for object in parent_list if object.pk not in set(filter1 + filter2)]
#                                                                   ^
```

The size of the entire search space is also reduced as duplicate items are removed from the set.

Found this [somewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8929320/3125566) on SO:

> Sets are implemented using hash tables. Whenever you add an object to
>   a set, the position within the memory of the set object is determined
>   using the hash of the object to be added. When testing for membership,
>   all that needs to be done is basically to look if the object is at the
>   position determined by its hash, so the speed of this operation does
>   not depend on the size of the set. For lists, in contrast, the whole
>   list needs to be searched, which will become slower as the list grows.

Comment: Two follow up questions: **1)** do I need to convert the set to a list (i.e. list(set(filter1+filter2)) for this to work **2)** this sort of a thing won't work with ValuesQuerySet would it?

Comment: Force the QuerySets to evaluate their items by slicing: `set(filter1[:] + filter2[:])`. You don't need to convert the `set` to a `list`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do it as below:

```
final_list = [object for object in parent_list if (object.pk not in filter1) and (object.pk not in filter2)]
```

I recomend make two sets `filter1` and `filter2` with the `object.pk` to be filtered just bc getting an element from a set it's faster

Comment: I think you want to use `and`, not `or`.

Comment: Thanks Mahendra, going with Moses' answer on this one since it had some extra optimization in it.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use:

```
final_list = [object for object in parent_list if object.pk not in filter1+filter2]
```

Comment: Thanks Nikign, going with Moses on this one.