# Does OrderedSet() still have a search parameter of O(1)?

Tags: python, set, ordered-set

I have heard that when you perform an `in` operator on a list it has to search through O(n) objects while if you do it on a set it has to search through O(1) objects.  To see what I mean go [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8929284/what-makes-sets-faster-than-lists).  Does this still apply to  `OrderedSet`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which `OrderedSet` are you talking about? At this time (Python 3.8.3), there is not `OrderedSet` in the standard library.

*Typically*, OrderedSet implementations will implement `__contains__` by delegating to the underlying `set`. So it will have the algorithmic complexity you would expect.

Comment: I was talking about ```OrderedSet``` from collections but your answer still works.

Comment: There is no `OrderedSet` in collections. There is a separate module, but that is not part of Standard Library.

Comment: Oh snap, I was thinking of ```OrderedDict```.  Sorry.