# Using two lists of indices to search through a third list

Tags: python, python-3.x

Suppose I have two lists of indices

```
letters = ['a', 'c']
numbers = ['1','2','6']
```

These lists are generated based on an interactive web interface element and is a necessary part of this scenario.

What is the most computationally efficient way in python I can use these two lists to search through the third list below for items?

```
list3 = ['pa1','pa2','pa3','pa4','pa5','pa6',
         'pb1','pb2','pb3','pb4','pb5','pb6',
         'pc1','pc2','pc3','pc4','pc5','pc6',
         'pd1','pd2','pd3','pd4','pd5','pd6']
```

Using the letters and numbers lists, I want to search through list3 and return this list

```
sublist = ['pa1', 'pa2, 'pa6', 'pc1', 'pc2', 'pc6']
```

I could do something like this:

```
sublist = []
for tag in list3:
    for l in letters:
        for n in numbers:
            if l in tag and n in tag:
                sublist.append(tag)
```

But I'm wondering if there's a better or more recommended way?

Comment: Take a look at [itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) and [sets](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_sets.asp). Itertools product can quickly generate the combination `pa1`, `pa2` etc ... and the sets can be used to quickly test membership (is an item contained in a set). The main update is that `set` memberships tests are O(1), take only 1 cycle, while `list`  membership take O(n), the number of elements in the list, cycles.

Comment: Thank you for this insight. Followup question, why is it that set membership tests take O(1) whereas list membership tests take O(n)?

Comment: See the SO questions: [What makes sets faster than lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8929284/what-makes-sets-faster-than-lists/8929445).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of all, do *not* iterate through the character lists.  Instead, use simple `in` operations; use `any` or `all` operations where necessary.  In this case, since your tags are all of the form `p[a-d][0-9]`, you can directly check the appropriate character:

```
for tag in list3:
    if tag[1] in "ac" and tag[2] in "126":
        sublist.append(tag)
```

For many uses or a generalized case, replace the strings with sets for **O(1)** time:

```
letter = set('a', 'c')
number = set('1', '2', '6')
for tag in list3:
    if tag[1] in letter and tag[2] in number:
        sublist.append(tag)
```

Next, get rid of the **O(n^2)** `append` series (adding to a longer list each time).  Replace it with a list comprehension.

```
sublist = [tag for tag in list3 
               if tag[1] in letter and tag[2] in number]
```

If the letters and numbers can appear *anywhere* in the list, then you need a general search for each: look for an overlap in character sets:

```
sublist = [tag for tag in list3 
               if any(char in letter for char in tag) and
                  any(char in number for char in tag)
          ]
```

or with sets:

```
sublist = [tag for tag in list3 
               if set(tag).intersection(letter) and
                  set(tag).intersection(number)
          ]
```

Comment: Thank you. Forgot I could pick out chars from strings using list notation in python. This is an excellent answer and well explained.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, in simple way

```
letters = ['a', 'c']
numbers = ['1','2','6']
sublist = []
result = []

list3 = ['pa1','pa2','pa3','pa4','pa5','pa6',
         'pb1','pb2','pb3','pb4','pb5','pb6',
         'pc1','pc2','pc3','pc4','pc5','pc6',
         'pd1','pd2','pd3','pd4','pd5','pd6']

for letter in letters:
    sublist.extend(list(filter(lambda tag: letter in tag, list3)))

for number in numbers:
    result.extend(list(filter(lambda tag: number in tag, sublist)))

print(result)
```