# "in" operation on sets and lists in Python

Tags: python

I have a book on Python which says:

> `in` is a very fast operation on sets:
>
> ```
> stopwords_list = ["a", "an"] + hundreds_of_other_words + ["yet", "you"]
> "zip" in stopwords_list # False, but have to check every element
> stopwords_set = set(stopwords_list)
> "zip" in stopwords_set # Very fast to check
> ```

I have two questions:

1. Why is `in` faster on sets than on lists?
2. If the `in` operator really is faster on sets, then why don't the makers of Python just rewrite the `in` method for lists to do `x in set(list)`? Why can't the idea in this book just be made part of the language?

Comment: because creating a `set` out of the list costs CPU

Comment: Also because not everything that can go in a list can go in a set.

Comment: As for efficiency, `x in set(list)` is the same as `x in list`. Both are linear operations.

Answer (score 2):

`set` uses hash tables to get an average `O(1)` lookup instead of `O(n)` lookup with lists, that's why it's way faster, provided the elements are hashable (read more: [What makes sets faster than lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8929284/what-makes-sets-faster-than-lists)).

Now converting a `list` into a `set` when `in` is called requires the full list to be parsed and converted to `set`, so it's even slower that searching in a list (even if the element is at the start of the list, the conversion is done on all the elements so there's no short-circuiting).

There's no magic. Converting a `list` into a `set` is useful, but only at init phase, and then the lookup is done in the `set` multiple times during the processing.

But in that case, creating a `set` directly is the best way.