# "Undirected" tuple comparison

Tags: python, tuples

I am currently working on an undirected graph in python, where the edges are represented by tuples (edge between A and B is represented by either (A,B) or (B,A)). I was wondering whether there is a tuple operation that performs an undirected comparison of tuples like this:

```
exp1 = undirected_comp((A,B), (B,A))    #exp1 should evaluate to True
exp2 = undirected_comp((A,B), (A,C))    #exp2 should evaluate to False
```

Comment: The short answer is no, but it wouldn't be hard to make. Also, `'tupel' != 'tuple'`.

Comment: Sounds to me like sets would be a better fit here.

Comment: Take a look a sets http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset

Comment: The problem with sets is that they don't have the "fixed length" vibe tuples have. For non-hypergraphs, edges are between exactly two vertices, not more and not less. @LukasGraf among others

Answer (score 4, accepted):

not exactly, but in general, you can do this kind of comparison with

```
set (A,B) == set (B, A)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That is exactly what i need in my case. Just one follow up question: if i use this to compare two tuple variables, their type is changed 'persistently', isn't it? So after the comparison, they are sets and not tuples any more.

Comment: No, if you do this: `t = (1,2); ts = set(t)`, `t` still is a tuple.

Answer (score 3):

Sure:
`undirected_comp = lambda e1,e2:   e1==e2 or (e1[1],e1[0])==e2`

Since edges are always exactly 2-tuples it should be robust enough, assuming the A and B objects have equality defined.

EDIT (shameless self-promotion): You probably don't want the overhead of creating two `set` objects for each comparator, especially if this is part of a larger algorithm.  Sets are great for look up but the instantiation is much slower: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7717668/837451

Comment: well.... yes and no. for this specific case where it's a 2-ple, then the special case comparison is faster, and just as simple. for general case (3 and up), sets make up lost time quickly. also, _lists_ are pretty expensive to generate - if you can generate a tuple instead, and generate a set from that (which you are going), it's considerably faster (though still slower here).

Comment: interesting point about lists.  however, given that the usage case is edges in a graph which--except for the relatively exotic case of hypergraphs--are _always_ 2-ples and can easily grow very large, the loss of generality is inconsequential and the speedup is likely to be noticed.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the solutions using sets, it is easy enough to roll your own comparison function:

```
In [1]: def undirected_comp(tup1, tup2):
   ...:     return tup1 == tup2 or tup1 == tup2[::-1]

In [2]: undirected_comp(('A','B'), ('B','A'))
Out[2]: True

In [3]: undirected_comp(('A','B'), ('A','C'))
Out[3]: False

In [4]: undirected_comp(('A','B'), ('A','B'))
Out[4]: True
```

As noted  by mmdanziger, this is faster than the solution with the sets, since you do not have to pay the cost of the set creation.

But if you care about speed **and** you spend more time on comparing various edges than on creating them, it is probably best not to store the edges as a tuple with arbitrary order, but to pre-process them and store them in a different format. The two best options would probably be a `frozenset` or a sorted tuple (i.e. by convention, you always store the smallest node first). Some quick timing:

```
# edge creation, this time is spent only once, so presumably we don't care:
In [1]: tup1 = (1, 2); tup2 = (2, 1)
In [2]: fs1 = frozenset(tup1); fs2 = frozenset(tup2)
In [3]: sorted_tup1 = tuple(sorted(tup1)); sorted_tup2 = tuple(sorted(tup2))

# now time the comparison operations
In [4]: timeit set(tup1) == set(tup2) # Corley's solution
1000000 loops, best of 3: 674 ns per loop

In [5]: timeit tup1 == tup2 or tup1 == tup2[::-1] # my solution above
1000000 loops, best of 3: 348 ns per loop

In [6]: timeit fs1 == fs2 # frozensets
10000000 loops, best of 3: 120 ns per loop

In [7]: timeit sorted_tup1 == sorted_tup2 # pre-sorted tuples
10000000 loops, best of 3: 83.4 ns per loop
```

So assuming that you don't care about the creation time of the edges, storing them as a sorted tuple is the fastest for doing the comparisons. In this case, you only have to do a simple comparison and do not have to compare the backwards case, since the order is guaranteed by the pre-sorting.

Answer (score 1):

Python tuples are ordered, while python sets are not. You could simply convert the tuples to sets before comparison using `set`.

```
(A,B) == (B,A))          # evaluates to false
set((A,B)) == set((B,A)) # evaluates to true
set((A,B) == set((A,C))  # evaluates to false
```

If you want to use a function, you could do something like this:

```
def undirected_comp(a,b):
     return (set(a) == set(b))
```

**Edit**: I was using `cmp()` to do comparisons, which was incorrect since it returns `1` if true and `-1` if false, rather than boolean. Changed the function to use `==`, which should return boolean - if you want `1` and `-1`, use `return cmp(set(a), set(b))`.

Comment: Actually `cmp((A,B), (B,A))` evaluates to 1 or -1, which don't equal False. The returned expression should be `set(a) == set(b)`.

Comment: @RobertoBonvallet: Oh, shoot, you're right. Since OP called his function "undirected_comp," I assumed he wanted to use `cmp()`. Could just change the function to use `==`.