# Python compare tuples

Tags: python, list, compare

Hello I want to compare  a list to another list in Python where the sequence of the elements doens't matters

eg

```
list=[1,2,3]
```

should be equal to `list2=[3,2,1]` and equal to `list3=[3,1,2]` etc. I want to do it dynamically because I don't know how many elements exist at the list? Is there any quick way to do it? The only way I came up with is to search each list for the elements of the other list but this has O(n^2). Also I cannot sort the list since in my implementation the list are list of list. I just want an answer for the simple version of the problem and then modify it! Can you help me?

Comment: Unfortunately, the easiest solution might _still_ be to sort the inner lists with a custom sorting key.

Comment: You might also want to take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21029678/undirected-tuple-comparison

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply convert the lists to sets and then simply check if they are equal

```
list1, list2, list3 = [1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 1], [1, 2, 3, 4]
print set(list1) == set(list2)    # True
print set(list2) == set(list3)    # False
print set(list1) == set(list3)    # False
```

If you want to make sure that the the elements exists only the same number of times as in the other list, you can use [`collections.counter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) ([Thanks @delnan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21364883/python-compare-tuples/21364894#comment32215889_21364894)), like this

```
list1, list2, list3, list4 = [1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 1], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 3]
from collections import Counter
print Counter(list1) == Counter(list2)    # True
print Counter(list2) == Counter(list3)    # False
print Counter(list1) == Counter(list3)    # False
print Counter(list1) == Counter(list4)    # False
```

Comment: @NG. Perhaps it does exactly what OP wants, hard to tell. And if not, `collections.Counter` works just as well.

Comment: @NG. I dont have any duplicates so it will work! Thx for the answer I will mark it as soon as possible!

Comment: @delnan Thanks :) I have included that in the answer :)

Answer (score 2):

If the lists are allowed to have the duplicate elements:

```
def list_eql(x, y):
    return sorted(x) == sorted(y)
```

If the lists don't have the duplicate elements:

```
def list_eql(x, y):
    return set(x) == set(y)
```

EDIT: as I've understood your question `x` and `y` are the lists of lists.
In that case `set` solution won't work (since lists are mutable) and you'll need to convert the inner lists to tuples first:

```
def list_eql(x, y):
    return set(map(tuple, x)) == set(map(tuple, y))
```

Comment: Just checking the length of two lists won't work if lists have duplicates.
Consider lists x=[1,1,2,2,3], y=[1,1,1,2,3]. Your function will return true, even if these two lists are not equal.