# Filter a list of dictionaries based on another list of strings

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries such as below

```
data = [{'Person1':['a', 'b', 'c']}, {'Person2':['1', '2', '3']}, {'Person3':['x', 'y', 'z']}]
```

and it consists of almost 7000000 dictionaries. Then I have a list of strings such as

```
people = ['person1', 'person3']
```

that is of length 450000. All of the strings in this list exist as keys in the list of dictionaries.

What is the fastest/most efficient way to filter the list of dictionaries based on this list of strings, so as to get back a new dictionary that only contains keys that corresponds to the strings in the list such as

```
d = {'Person1':['a', 'b', 'c']}, 'Person3':['x', 'y', 'z']}
```

This is my code, but it takes a really long time to run, and I was wondering what the best way to approach this is.

```
d = {}

for p in people:
    for i in data:
        for k in i:
            if p == k.lower():
               d[p] = i[k]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few benchmarks -

#### Nested For loops

```
%%timeit

out = []
for i in data:
    for j in people:
        if list(i.keys())[0]==j:
            out.append(i)
            
#1.78 µs ± 55.1 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

#### List comprehension with `in`

```
%%timeit

out = [i for i in data if list(i.keys())[0] in people]

#1.02 µs ± 36.8 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

#### List comprehension with `set.intersection`

```
%%timeit

out = [i for i in data if set(i).intersection(people)]

#1.04 µs ± 27.9 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 1):

A first suggestion using dict-comprehension:

```
from collections import ChainMap

data = [
    {'Person1':['a', 'b', 'c']}, 
    {'Person2':['1', '2', '3']}, 
    {'Person3':['x', 'y', 'z']}
]
people = ['Person1', 'Person3']

big_dict = dict(ChainMap(*data))

# drop duplicates
people = list(set(people))

smaller_dict = {person: big_dict[person] for person in people}
```

For ChainMap see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23392976/what-is-the-purpose-of-collections-chainmap).
I used `people` as a list (not as a set) because [it has been reported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25272400/which-one-is-faster-iterating-over-a-set-and-iterating-over-a-list) that lists perform slightly faster in these cases.

Comment: I would suggest not to use `set()` to change datatype because the `overhead for creating sets can be significant` as suggested by the link you share above and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7717011/which-is-faster-and-why-set-or-list/7717668#7717668)

Comment: Since we are doing it only once it might be bearable, especially if we eliminate several entries from `people`. If the list contains no duplicates, we can drop this line for sure.

Comment: That's true. also, you can avoid that problem by using `in` as well.