# Pulling from List using If/Else statement - Python

Tags: python, list

I want to match the correct terms from my list. Here is my code:

```
stuff = ["cat", "dog", "house", "cat", "mouse"]

for item in stuff:
    if "house" in item:
        print "house good"
    if "cat" in item:
        print "cat good"
    if "dog" in item:
        print "dog good"
    else:
        print "nothing else"
```

The results are currently this:

```
cat good
nothing else
dog good
house good
nothing else
cat good
nothing else
nothing else
```

But I want the results to be this:

```
cat good
dog good
house good 
cat good 
nothing else
```

Currently the script keeps pulling "nothing else" because of my else statement. But I don't know how to only making "nothing else" come up exclusively when a term in my list doesn't match the terms in my if statements. Does anyone know I can do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using `elif`, like so:

```
for item in stuff:
    if "house" in item:
        print "house good"
    elif "cat" in item:
        print "cat good"
    elif "dog" in item:
        print "dog good"
    else:
        print "nothing else"
```

Otherwise the `else` only applies to the last `if`.

Answer (score 2):

You should make all the conditions part of the same statement, by using `elif`. Currently the else only applies to the last condition.

```
if "house" in item:
    print "house good"
elif "cat" in item:
    print "cat good"
elif "dog" in item:
    print "dog good"
else:
    print "nothing else"
```

Comment: Obviously. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

you must use elif condition like :

```
stuff = ["cat", "dog", "house", "cat", "mouse"]

for item in stuff:
    if "house" in item:
        print ("house good")
    elif "cat" in item:
        print ("cat good")
    elif "dog" in item:
        print ("dog good")
    else:
        print ("nothing else")
```

Answer (score 0):

Other answers suggest that you should be using a `elif` statement to fix your code. This is perfectly reasonable. However, I just wanted to point out that with a slight refactoring of your code you can make it simpler, more readable, and more extendable:

```
stuff = ["cat", "dog", "house", "cat", "mouse"]
good_stuff = set(["house", "cat", "dog"])

for item in stuff:
    if item in good_stuff:
        print item + " good"
    else:
        print "nothing else"
```

Any time that you find yourself using `if`, `elif`, `elif`, `elif`, ... it is usually because you have [designed your code badly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1554691/341459).

> Note that I am using a `set` here for optimisation purposes. If you don't know why, then I suggest you look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7717046/341459).

Answer (score 0):

Try not to use 'in', if I was you I will try to use '=='.

But judging that it is already in the list, so you won't need the 'for' part I guess, just 'if xxx in stuff'

Hope this helps!